django-python3-ldap Auth only specific groups
Hoping someone can help me debug an issue I have using django-python3-ldap.
I have been able to get authentication working but need to be able to only authenticate users that are in a specific AD Group ("BI - Admin" within MSBI),
Here is my code that is working (for authenticating all users)
Settings.py:
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend"]
#AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "LDAP://SERVERNAME"
LDAP_AUTH_URL = ["LDAP://SERVERNAME:389"]
LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = False
import ssl
LDAP_AUTH_TLS_VERSION = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "cn=users,dc=DOMAIN,dc=org"
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "user"
LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
"username": "sAMAccountName",
"first_name": "givenName",
"last_name": "sn",
"email": "mail",
}
LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)

LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"

LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"

from apprum.ldap_filters import custom_format_search_filters

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "apprum.ldap_filters.custom_format_search_filters"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory_principal"

LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = "domain.org"`

ldap_filters.py :
from django_python3_ldap.utils import format_search_filters

def custom_format_search_filters(ldap_fields):
    #ldap_fields["memberOf"] = "BI - Admin"
    search_filters = format_search_filters(ldap_fields)
    # Advanced: apply custom LDAP filter logic.
    #search_filters.append("(|(memberOf=BI - Team))")
    #search_filters.append("(&(memberOf=cn=BI - Admin,OU=MSBI,DC=domain,dc=org))")
    # All done!
    print(search_filters)
    return search_filters

Structure of Active Directory:
Domain.org --> Groups -> MSBI -> BI - Admin
Domain.org --> Users -> Adam.Wally

"Adam.Wally" is a user in my test AD and a member of BI - Admin.
So in theory that account should be authenticated.. Well, Thats what I am aiming for,
If I uncomment ldap_fields["memberOf"] = "BI - Admin", I get the following in the terminal
LDAP connect succeeded
['(sAMAccountName=adam.wally)', '(objectClass=user)', '(memberOf=BI - Admin)']
LDAP user lookup failed

Am i missing anything obvious?
Thanks in advance!

How does the AD entry look like? In our AD it would be (with your sample data):
memberOf=cn=BI - Admin,OU=MSBI,DC=domain,dc=org

So, in your code, you'd have for ldap_filters.py:
from django_python3_ldap.utils import format_search_filters

def custom_format_search_filters(ldap_fields):
    ldap_fields["memberOf"] = "cn=BI - Admin,OU=MSBI,DC=domain,dc=org"
    search_filters = format_search_filters(ldap_fields)
    print(search_filters)
    return search_filters

